# Django urls.py import not detecting

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a working api, and I am writing a UI to the API, as a separate application in the same project. My project urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import *
import search
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^api/search$', search.validation),
url(r'^ui', include('ui.urls')),
)
```

My UI app's urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import *
import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^ui/$', views.search_template),
)
```

However, when I am trying to access with my browser(`domain.com:8000/ui`), I am getting an error.

```
Using the URLconf defined in api.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^api/search$
^ui ^ui$
```

The current URL, ui, didn't match any of these.

But if I use the below mapping in the main project's urls.py, it works.
(r'^ui$', ui.views.user_template),

I tried clearing the urls.pyc to make sure it is not stale, but it still persists. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't repeat `ui` regex in the app's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', views.search_template),
)
```